# Copy multiple worksheets into one

Tags: vba, excel

I have spent a while searching for help on writing code to copy matching data from multiple worksheets into a single sheet, but the only one that did something similar that I found was located here: [Find Match, Copy Row from Sheet1 and Insert Into Sheet2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806170/find-match-copy-row-from-sheet1-and-insert-into-sheet2)

I tried adapting it to fit my needs, but I am not very good at VBA and I could not get it to do what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I have is a workbook that has four worksheets; `Master`, `FescoMonthly`, `Schedule`, and `FescoData`. These worksheets are sent to us by our customers so I can import them, but I do not want to change their layouts, which is part of the problem. I want the macro to search for matching meter numbers in every worksheet and copy certain row to a new worksheet called `Combined`.

In the `Master` worksheet I need to copy the whole thing from row 5 to bottom (currently 1982 but more could be added) and columns A through F. -----Column A is meter number

In the `FescoMonthly` worksheet I need to copy row 5 to bottom and column A through H by matching identical meter numbers from column D (meter number) to column A of the main worksheet.

In the `Schedule` worksheet I need to copy row 5 to bottom and column A through D by matching column A (meter number) to column A of the main worksheet.

In the `FescoData` worksheet I need to copy row 5 to bottom and column A through C by matching column A (meter number) to column A of the main worksheet.

If someone could please help me with just matching and copying `Master` and `FescoMonthly` I think I could figure out how to do the others and I could repost my work to see if I am doing it right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help need Pls.... excel macro: compare and copy between worksheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692345/help-need-pls-excel-macro-compare-and-copy-between-worksheets)

Comment: The page you pointed to is asking for 3 sets of duplicates on two worksheets, but I am asking for one duplicate on 4 worksheets. I am sorry, but I am not advanced enough to figure out my answer from that post. Thank you for helping to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you mean you want to skip meter numbers from `FescoMonthly` which match meter numbers in `Master` and then copy the rest from `FescoMonthly` to a new sheet?

Comment: No. Sorry I guess my description is not very good. Each worksheet has different information on it. The master worksheet has every meter number that I will ever see and the FescoMonthly has information about SOME of the meters. I want the macro to take this information and add it in the columns next to the right of the master data, but in a new worksheet. It would also do this for the other two worksheets. In the end I want to have one row of ALL of the data available for a meter number.

Comment: Three sets of duplicates on two worksheets is no different than one duplicate on four worksheets. You have the logic there of working with **duplicates** and **more than one worksheet**, which is all you need.

Comment: Again I apologize that this is so simple for you, but I am a beginner to this. The example you gave does not show me how to copy the data after it has been matched to a new worksheet.

If you could just help me with doing one page I will try to figure the others out from there, but the example seems to be totally different from what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

set sht to the worksheet that has the data you want to copy
set trg to the target worksheet
set colCount to the number of columns to copy

```
Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(5, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount)) 
' start at row 5, then get the last row with data, and then expand to the  number of columns
trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value 
' find last unused cell in first column, and copy the data there
```

(use 1048576 instead of 65536 in excel 2007 or later)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but all this does is copy the data to the new worksheet. What I am looking to do is match up the information in 4 worksheets together into one worksheet.

Comment: vlookup will work across files. I don't know if that would help

Comment: That is kind of what I was doing in the first place, but I was hoping to get a macro because the workbook is constantly changing and if I had a macro I think it would work better because I could make the changes and then just hit the button to pull the correct info into a new worksheet.